# how to deal with multine messages in log files using logstash

Tags: logstash

I am using beats for file path in logstash and I want to merge multiline messages into a single event, I am using codec in my config file but it is not working, I am getting an error as below

> Failed to execute action
>   {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
>   :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of
>   , { at line 8, column 8 (byte 169) after # The # character at the beginning of a li e indicates a comment. Use\n# cooments to describe
>   your configuration.\ninput {\n    beats{\n\tport => \"5044\"\n
>   }\n  \n codec ",

Comment: Post your logstash configuration, there is a syntax error in it.

Comment: please post your configuration as well as your log